# errors using neo4j gem for non-rails (ruby-only)

Tags: neo4j, neo4j.rb, graphenedb

From the documentation: http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.x/Setup.html

`neo4j_adaptor = Neo4j::Core::CypherSession::Adaptors::HTTP.new('http://user:pass@host:7474')
Neo4j::ActiveBase.on_establish_session { Neo4j::Core::CypherSession.new(neo4j_adaptor) }`

I get:

`NameError: uninitialized constant Neo4j::Core::CypherSession`

To fix, I added (not documented in the above):

`require 'neo4j/core/cypher_session/adaptors/http'`

The error changes (the first line works):

`Neo4j::ActiveBase.on_establish_session { Neo4j::Core::CypherSession.new(neo4j_adaptor) }
NameError: uninitialized constant Neo4j::ActiveBase`

Is there a better place to see how to set up working with a heroku-based grapheneDB?  I keep hitting undocumented errors when doing a cut-and-paste of the set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out the missing `require`.  I've just added it (also feel free to click "Edit on GitHub" at the top to start a pull request if you notice anything else)

Have you done a `require "neo4j"`?  That should bring in `ActiveBase` and all of the `ActiveNode` / `ActiveRel` stuff.  If that works I can add that to the docs as well

Comment: I did originally `require "neo4j"` but I realize that because I was hitting the original error on an old session I was hitting the error for missing `ActiveBase` but it now works.  Thnk you.